# Parse json object in android

Tags: android, json

I try parsing a single json object and i have a problem.
this is my object :

```
{"id":"16","nickname":"vvvv","country":"Albania","date":"2013-03-25 21:08:40","best":"8","updateDate":"1364243187.162"}
```

i use this code:

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(responce).nextValue();
         String query = object.getString("nickname");
```

i get java.langClassCastExeption java.jangBoolean

Comment: I recommend using _GSON_.

Comment: Or Jackson - great mapping tool

Comment: What is exact exception you got?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply create an JSONObject from given string and then extract all values from jsonObject as :

```
 //create json object form responce string
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(responce);

//get nickname
 String query = object.getString("nickname");
///.... get other value for object
```

and also use [JSONObject.has(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) for checking is current json object contain mapping for given name or not

Comment: @allpnay : have u tried my suggestion. if yes plz edit your question with latest code to get more help. because your json string contain only one jsonObject and not contain any boolean value